# Delphi OpenOffice automation scalc center cell text

Tags: delphi, automation, openoffice.org, cells, centering

Hello could someone please help me with the following:
I want to center the text in a scalc open office spreadsheet cell via Delphi and the OOoTools toolkit.

The following code does not work:

```
sRange := '$A$3:$A$3';
ooParams := CreateUnoStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue', 1);
ooParams[0].Name  := 'ToPoint';
ooParams[0].Value := sRange;
execDispatch('.uno:GoToCell', ooParams);

ooParams := CreateUnoStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue', 1);
ooParams[0].Name  := 'HorizontalJustification';
ooParams[0].Value := 'com.sun.star.table.CellHoriJustify.CENTER';
execDispatch('.uno:HorizontalJustification', ooParams);
```

Has someone any idea why not?
Thanks Ad

Comment: Latest version 1.3 of OOoTools by Bernard Marcelly is here now:

http://bernard.marcelly.perso.sfr.fr/index2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that HorizontalJustification needs an enumvalue, but you're giving a string. You have to lookup the value of `com.sun.star.table.CellHoriJustify.CENTER` and fill your `ooParams[0].Value` with it.

Here is a way to lookup an enumvalue: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=16383

In your case `com.sun.star.table.CellHoriJustify.CENTER` equals 2, so you need:

```
ooParams[0].Name  := 'HorizontalJustification';
ooParams[0].Value := 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, that works, also I had to fill in a 0 for the last parameter in: 
    ooParams := CreateUnoStruct('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue', 0);
Kind Regards Ad.

Comment: The last parameter of CreateUnoStruct specifies the maximum index of the sequence (VarArray) you want to create. So when you say 1, you get a VarArray with 2 elements [0..1], but you only need 1 element [0..0], so maximumindex is 0.